# How to add bullet when user inputs new line

Tags: java, android

I have a multiline editText in my activity. And what I want is ecerytime the user inputs new line / next line / enter , a bullet should be generated automatically. What should I do? Below is an example of the expected output:

```
• Item 1 (user presses enter / new line)
•
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'm not sure about is if you also want the first line to get a bullet automatically. Try this for getting a bullet in the new line:

```
final EditText et = findViewById(R.id.edittext);
et.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent event) {
        // onKey is fired twice, we filter one out
        if (event.getAction()!=KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            return false;
        }

        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            String oldString = et.getText().toString();
            String newString =  oldString + "\u25CF";
            et.setText(newString);
            et.setSelection(et.getText().length());
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a character to do this.

• = `\u2022`
● = `\u25CF`

You should be able to add one to the editbox.

```
yourBox.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override public boolean onKey (View v,int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            String myString = yourBox.getText().toString();
            yourBox.setText("\u25CF " + myString);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```